# Parent class function access in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have two child classes B and C which inherit from one parent class A. Is it possible that I can make certain functions of class A accessible in B but not in C in java?

Comment: This is not a good idea and likely what you're asking is an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info), in that you're trying to solve a problem the wrong way. Also, look up the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) to see some underpinnings of why this is a bad idea.

Comment: Probably the best you can do is to have C override the method and inside the override, throw an UnsupportedOperationException. And then document the hell out of this so as not to upset any users of C.

Comment: Of course you can! And you can do it using polymorphism. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html. Just implement in class C, the same methods  declared on A, so the methods in class C contain a different implementation. There is a catch: This is a code smell, this means, it is possible that the design of your classes A, B and C are very, very wrong.

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero: that does not do what the OP is requesting

Comment: If the method doesn't have to be public, you can make it package-private, put `B` in the same package as `A`, and `C` in a different package.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: That depends of what the OP is trying to do: Muhammad Ali, what are you trying to achieve with this? Can you show us some code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to forbid to call `destroyEverything()` from class C:

```
public class A {

  public void travel() {
     System.out.println("Travel from A");
  }

  public void makePee() {
     System.out.println("Call from A");
  }

}

public class B extends A {

  public void travel() {
     super.travel();
     System.out.println("Travel from B");
  }

   public void makePee() {
      super.makePee();
      System.out.println("Call from B");
   }

}
```

Then, on C:

```
public class C extends A {

  public void travel() {
     super.travel();
     System.out.println("Travel from C");
  }

   public void makePee(){
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported from C");
   }
}
```

BUT, if what you want is to *not inherit stuff from A*, it is probably a flaw at the design of your class hierarchy and class C should not inherit from A.

Example of design flaw: Class A is **Animal**, class B is **Beaver**, and you want your class C **Cadillac** to inherit stuff from **Animal** since **Animal** already has the method **travel**.

Since maybe you don't want to inherit the method **makePee** (every animal urinates, but **Cadillacs** don't), it is better to move **Cadillacs** (class C) to another class hierarchy or find another class design

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It helped me

Answer (score 1):

Well i don't know a way to forbid it in the Code. But you could just override and then don'f fill them.

Answer (score 0):

As per my thinking it is not possible.

Let's see the one real time example->
A Parent have a two child then both are able to access parent property .it is there no restriction on that you can not use this or you can not use this.

And if you want to do like that then you can implicitly write logic in B class also